# Cron job not working due to wget error

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I'm setting up a CRON job on my MediaTemple DV4 to generate a sitemap. To test I ran the command via the command line:

```
 wget http://subdomain.website.com/?sm_command=build&sm_key=348791hdshjfjdkaiu34
```

and I get the following error:

```
 Reusing existing connection to subdomain.website.com:80.
```

Here is the full output:

```
 Resolving subdomain.website.com... 12.345.678.90
 Connecting to subdomain.website.com|12.345.678.90|:80... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
 Location: http://subdomain.website.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsubdomain.website.com%2F%3Fsm_command%3Dbuild [following]
 --2013-04-18 11:36:21--  http://subdomain.website.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsubdomain.website.com%2F%3Fsm_command%3Dbuild
 Reusing existing connection to subdomain.website.com:80.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: unspecified [text/html]
 Saving to: `wp-login.php?redirect_to=http:%2F%2Fsubdomain.website.com%2F?sm_command=build.6'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Put the URL between single quotes to prevent special characteres from being interpreted

Comment: My thought is that maybe the command hadn't completed from the last run? I doubt the problem is w/ wget or cron, I'd look at the webervers logs.